# What is the exact difference between Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac

We are planning to develop native cross platform mobile apps using Xamarin, so we are trying to evaluate Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.iOS.

What is the exact difference between Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.iOS? and which one exact fit for Cross platform mobile apps development.

Thanks,

Ravi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xamarin.Mac is for OS X desktop apps.

Xamarin.iOS is for iOS apps.

Xamarin.Android is for Android apps.